# Java For Loop Problems

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, cycle

```
JButton nupp0 = new JButton(); // Teen nupu objektid, rida 54 
JButton nupp1 = new JButton();
JButton nupp2 = new JButton();
JButton nupp3 = new JButton();
JButton nupp4 = new JButton();
JButton nupp5 = new JButton();
JButton nupp6 = new JButton();
JButton nupp7 = new JButton();

public JButton nupud[] = { nupp0, nupp1, nupp2, nupp3, nupp4, nupp5, nupp6, nupp7 };
```

I was told to create this pieace of code in for loop, Ive tried many ways, but I cant get it to work. Any Ideas?

These are my 2 tries:

```
for (int i =0 ; i < nupud.length ; i++) {
    JButton nupud[i] = new JButton;     
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < nupud.length ; i++) {
    nupud[i] = new JButton();
}
```

Comment: We all got for loop problems. Also, we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. Also, **review array syntax**.

Comment: The second snippet looks about right, assuming you've already initialized the array. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: What problem you are facing ?

Comment: Error says that "nupud cannot be resolved to a variable" , if u mean the very last peace of code

Comment: Seems like the problem is that I havent declared any variables, even "nupp" gives the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just new up the array first:

```
JButton[] nupud = new JButton[8];
for (int i = 0 ; i < nupud.length; i++){
    nupud[i] = new JButton();
}
```

Comment: and now the same for "nupp" as well ?

Comment: @user3086917 You shouldn't need the `nupp` variables anymore with this solution, this will initialize the array with 8 unique JButtons (you can change that value if you need more)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing this before the for loop.

```
JButton[] nupud = new JButton[length];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just check it my eclipse its work :

```
package com.demo.swain;

public class JButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JButton nupp0 = new JButton(); // Teen nupu objektid, rida 54 
        JButton nupp1 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp2 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp3 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp4 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp5 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp6 = new JButton();
        JButton nupp7 = new JButton();

     JButton[] nupud = { nupp0, nupp1, nupp2, nupp3, nupp4, nupp5, nupp6, nupp7};
        for (int i =0 ; i < nupud.length ; i++) {
            nupud[i] = new JButton();
                  System.out.println(nupud[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
com.demo.swain.JButton@dc74f8d
com.demo.swain.JButton@1837b90c
com.demo.swain.JButton@7255cf3f
com.demo.swain.JButton@5f996bbd
com.demo.swain.JButton@51707653
```